# Jersey client (2.x) does not send my GET request headers

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I've been debugging this for three hours, I still cannot explain why my custom headers (registered via a client request filter) are not sent.

The client is configured as such (full source [here](https://github.com/fbiville/vidal-jersey-client-example/tree/jersey_client_setup)):

```
private WebTarget webTarget(String host, String appId, String appKey) {
    return newClient(clientConfiguration(appId, appKey))
            .target(host + "/rest");
}

private Configuration clientConfiguration(String appId, String appKey) {
    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    config.register(requestFilter(appId, appKey));
    return config;
}

private ClientRequestFilter requestFilter(String appId, String appKey) {
    return new VidalRequestFilter(apiCredentials(appId, appKey));
}
```

The filter is as follows:

```
public class VidalRequestFilter implements ClientRequestFilter {

    private final ApiCredentials credentials;

    public VidalRequestFilter(ApiCredentials credentials) {
        this.credentials = credentials;
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = requestContext.getHeaders();
        headers.add(ACCEPT, APPLICATION_ATOM_XML_TYPE);
        headers.add("app_id", credentials.getApplicationId());
        headers.add("app_key", credentials.getApplicationKey());
    }
}
```

And the call is like:

```
String response = webTarget
    .path("api/packages")
    .request()
    .get()
    .readEntity(String.class);
```

All I get is 403 forbidden, because the specific endpoint I am calling is protected (the auth is performed with the custom headers defined above).

The weirdest thing is that, while I'm debugging, I see that `sun.net.www.MessageHeader` is properly invoked during the request write (i.e. the instance is valued as such: `sun.net.www.MessageHeader@14f9390f7 pairs: {GET /rest/api/packages HTTP/1.1: null}{Accept: application/atom+xml}{app_id: XXX}{app_key: YYY}{User-Agent: Jersey/2.22.1 (HttpUrlConnection 1.8.0_45)}{Host: ZZZ}{Connection: keep-alive}`.

However, I have the confirmation that neither our API server, nor its reverse proxy received GET requests with the required auth headers (a first HEAD request seems to be OK, though).

I know for sure the credentials are good 'cause the equivalent curl command just works!

I tried the straightforward approach to set headers directly when defining the call without any success.

What am I missing?

Comment: The headers are going through fine. I am proxying through Fiddler and can see all the headers are there.

Comment: I'll investigate a bit on server side, then. Thanks for testing.

Comment: I tested on a local server and the headers are properly sent. It seems related to another infrastructure issue. I guess I'll close the question for now.